# Is there a better way to format when converting text in "dd/mm/yyyy" to Date in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, dax, powerquery

My data-source is an Excel file with some date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format and due to some error, read the date as text to Power BI. 
When I tried to convert it to a valid date using dax DATEVALUE(text) function, unfortunately these only converting to mm/dd/yyyy format.

I found that this can be converted to a date by splitting the text as below:

```
ATTENDANCE_DATE = DATE(RIGHT(ATTENDANCE[SERVICEDATE],4), MID(ATTENDANCE[SERVICEDATE],4,2),LEFT(ATTENDANCE[SERVICEDATE],2))
```

Still wonders if there any better way exits for date formatting in Power BI?

Answer (score 4):

The best is to have the M query converted for you, i.e.

[image: convert to date]

[image: converted]

In case you're talking about how to **display** the date in a specific format, you should find the setting here:

[image: change date format]

Results:

[image: results]

Comment: Hi @rchacko Does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.